# [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]

Tags: c#

I am interested in using a DataObject and have been looking through the documentation.  I have seen this line used in regard to different methods in regard to exposing them to various calling tools, what do you ahve to do to get it to work?

[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]

I get an error message saying that the DataObjectMethodType is out of context?

How do I get a dataobject to use a function that I have written?

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the namespace on the DataOjbectMethod type.  Either of the following should fix it...

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
```

OR

```
using System.ComponentModel;

[DataObject]
class MyClass
{

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    IEnumerable<MyObject> MyMethod()
    {
        ...
```